Adding processing 4 to Intellji IDE
I have downloaded the Processing 4 zip, and unzipped it. Now I added the core.jar library to my project, but it seems like it's messing some libraries, the "gluegen" and "jogl", I have founded them next to the core.jar file and added them the same way but I still can't run the project...
This are all links to image, because I can't yet upload an image apparently...
jar files location
The libraries are recognized:
Error while runing
It's like not finding it, I don't know:
Modules in project structure
Modules in main
Maybe it's because it isn't in main? and if so how to fix?
I think this should solve it, but i need to do it to all the libraries:
Adding the library to classpath
Edit: I have added the jars file to the libraries but now I get this error:

from this code:
private PVector[] points;
private float rotateX, rotateY;
private float zoomScale = 1.0f;

public void settings() {
    size(800, 600, P3D);
}

public void setup() {
    points = new PVector[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        points[i] = new PVector(random(-100, 100), random(-100, 100), random(-100, 100));
    }
}

public void draw() {
    background(255);
    translate(width / 2, height / 2);
    scale(zoomScale);
    rotateX(rotateX);
    rotateY(rotateY);

    stroke(0);
    strokeWeight(2);
    line(-width, 0, 0, width, 0, 0); // X-axis
    line(0, -height, 0, 0, height, 0); // Y-axis
    line(0, 0, -width, 0, 0, width); // Z-axis

    noStroke();
    fill(0, 0, 255);
    for (PVector p : points) {
        pushMatrix();
        translate(p.x, p.y, p.z);
        sphere(5);
        popMatrix();
    }
}

public void mouseDragged() {
    rotateX += (pmouseY - mouseY) * 0.01f;
    rotateY += (mouseX - pmouseX) * 0.01f;
}

public void mouseWheel(MouseEvent event) {
    zoomScale += event.getCount() * 0.1f;
    zoomScale = constrain(zoomScale, 0.1f, 5.0f);
}

Ok, I have understood the problem there is no such directory:
C:\Users\hilai\Desktop\PleaseWork\natives\windows-amd64

The problem is that I don't know what to do now....

Not sure why the jars are not recognized or which ones could be missing, but when I had this problem, I added processing as maven-dependency, since I was already using maven in my project. If you're interested in that, here's the dependency:
org.processing
core
3.3.7

Tnx for the help, but im using gradle, sorry for the ignorance but is there a way to add proccesing with gradle?

You can find the repo here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.processing/core/3.3.7 There is also a gradle import listed

Processing 4 Maven/Gradle here: https://github.com/micycle1/processing-core-4

Ok so first of all the one who answered me did a great job, you should add those to your library. about the error that it cant find it in native.. you need to create the directory yourself and paste this files there.

this is what you need to create in your root project

In Project Structure add New Project Library, select Java option, select all three jars:

core.jar
gluegen-rt.jar
jogl-all.jar

[Apply] and [OK]

They should be now visible in Project:


I think it worked tnx

Ok it worked but im encountring  a new error

What error? Most problems are with incorporating the processing.core.PApplet in Main(). But you need to write it somewhere.
